# Cannot get GIT to push repository through terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, passwords, push

I have tried and tried and tried to figure this out but I am stuck. I cannot push my repository though my terminal on Macbook. I have deleted password out of keychain. Made a new password for GitHub. Tried to clear everything out and still get this message showing a "key" at the end of the password prompt. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG??[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFmKS.png)

Comment: Add the error messages from running the pushes.

Comment: Are you sure the key icon isn't just the terminal's way to indicate that your input will be hidden? (not sure which terminal you're using, but https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5179 is an example of that in iTerm)

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication enabled? https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication/#authenticating-on-the-command-line-using-https

Comment: It will not let me type where the key symbol is

Comment: On some terminals, typing the password on the prompt will not show up on the terminal (i.e. the cursor does not move), but it is still entered. See [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/q/112069/727997) (it's for Ubuntu, I know, but it's related) and [What does the Key icon mean when I type in a password in terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302797/253138) for Mac. Have you tried entering the password then hitting Enter?

Comment: I even read that article and still didn't get it. Thank you.